# How to get access to the MySQL from the Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, windows-phone-7, mysql-connector

I'm trying to implement an application which should get data from the remote MySQL server, but I don't found a mysql driver for the windows phone.
I have tried to google and search here but the best found solution is the service on the server side to provide my own API to get access to the database.
But I can't use proxy service at this project.
Is there a way to connect to mysql server from the Windows Phone application?

Answer (score 0):

No, connecting directly to databases is not supported. Windows Phone is oriented towards consuming services, preferably REST-like.

You should expose some sort of service on the server part. Even from the security standpoint allowing direct connections is very insecure.

What your web endpoint should is is exposing the minimum of functionality for your mobile app. You should not give full read or write access to the database, just design some endpoints with the mobile-specific data being exposed through them.

Comment: Unfortunately I need a windows phone application with direct access to mysql.

Comment: You can build your own driver then for that purpose. You *shouldn't* need to have such application. It is insecure by design. What are you building? MySQL admin/browser app for WP?

Comment: It's just a test work but it should be implemented. Now I'm trying to find a way to build small sudset of mysql native .NET driver.

Comment: So I have finished a porting of the mysql net driver to WP8